# How to create bubble that Looks like in Siri's UI

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, quartz-graphics, siri

I was looking out for the ways to create a UI bubble that looks like in Siri's UI.

I have previously created a iOS chat like UI in which I used the image and then played with its

```
    stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:
```

But, my take on this is, they are drawing the bubble using Quartz. But, as we all know it is a significant usage of the processor every time we do it.

Any suggestions?

Image Here
[image]

Comment: I have posted the completed code over here.. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010500/siri-chat-bubble-colors-in-ios

Answer (score 2):

Try using this same tutorial but add those graphical look. You can easily make that in photoshop. If you are a good programmer than ask a friend who is UI designer (I hate photoshop can't even get line straight....lol, So I always ask my friends who knows photoshop to make something like this)

This tutorial is Great!!!

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-bubble-ui-iphone-apps

Good luck!

Comment: Eh. It would be much lighter if it could be drawn using core graphics, or something. Creating an image just for this shape is probably overkill.