# Siri chat bubble color's in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, quartz-graphics, siri

I tried creating the Siri chat bubble in core graphics. I am at a stage where I can draw the shape. I am stuck with the color's here. Wanaa get the border color and the fill color code.
here is what I did so far..

```
- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)context
{

CGRect rect = gradientRectFrame;
CGFloat radius = 30;

CGFloat originBufferX = 0.0;
CGFloat originBufferY = 0.0;
CGFloat rightAngleTriangleWidth = 20.0;
CGFloat rightAngleTriangleHeight = 20.0;
CGFloat fullRectWidth = rect.size.width;
CGFloat fullRectHeight = rect.size.height;


CGPoint pointZero = CGPointMake(originBufferX, fullRectHeight);
CGPoint pointOne = CGPointMake(originBufferX + rightAngleTriangleWidth, fullRectHeight - rightAngleTriangleHeight);
CGPoint pointTwo = CGPointMake(originBufferX + rightAngleTriangleWidth, radius + originBufferY);
CGPoint pointThree = CGPointMake(originBufferX + fullRectWidth - radius, 0 + originBufferY);
CGPoint pointFour = CGPointMake(fullRectWidth, originBufferY + fullRectHeight - radius);    
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 105/255, 105/255, 105/255, 0.5);
 CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);


CGContextMoveToPoint(context, pointZero.x, pointZero.y);

CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, pointOne.x, pointOne.y);

CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, pointTwo.x, pointTwo.y);

CGContextAddArc(context, rightAngleTriangleWidth + radius, originBufferY + radius, radius, M_PI, -M_PI_2, 0);

CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, pointThree.x, pointThree.y);

CGContextAddArc(context, fullRectWidth - radius, originBufferY + radius, radius, -M_PI_2, 0.0f, 0);

CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, pointFour.x, pointFour.y);

CGContextAddArc(context, fullRectWidth - radius, originBufferY + fullRectHeight - radius, radius, 0.0f, M_PI_2, 0);

CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, pointZero.x, pointZero.y);

CGContextFillPath(context);

CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 50/255, 50/255, 50/255, 0.5);
```

//  CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

```
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

}

[image: Chat Bubble]

[image]

Updated Code: I m now using CGPath instead of CGContenxt to redraw my path after I fill my path. Here is the new Code. Although, my stroke color is not quite close yet..

```
- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)context

{

CGRect rect = gradientRectFrame;
CGFloat radius = 20;

CGFloat originBufferX = 0.0;
CGFloat originBufferY = 0.0;
CGFloat rightAngleTriangleWidth = 20.0;
CGFloat rightAngleTriangleHeight = 20.0;
CGFloat fullRectWidth = rect.size.width;
CGFloat fullRectHeight = rect.size.height;


CGPoint pointZero = CGPointMake(originBufferX, fullRectHeight);
CGPoint pointOne = CGPointMake(originBufferX + rightAngleTriangleWidth, fullRectHeight - rightAngleTriangleHeight);
CGPoint pointTwo = CGPointMake(originBufferX + rightAngleTriangleWidth, radius + originBufferY);
CGPoint pointThree = CGPointMake(originBufferX + fullRectWidth - radius, 0 + originBufferY);
CGPoint pointFour = CGPointMake(fullRectWidth, originBufferY + fullRectHeight - radius);    

CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.3);

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, pointZero.x, pointZero.y);

CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, pointOne.x, pointOne.y);

CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, pointTwo.x, pointTwo.y);

CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, rightAngleTriangleWidth + radius, originBufferY + radius, radius, M_PI, -M_PI_2, 0);

CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, pointThree.x, pointThree.y);

CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, fullRectWidth - radius, originBufferY + radius, radius, -M_PI_2, 0.0f, 0);

CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, pointFour.x, pointFour.y);

CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, fullRectWidth - radius, originBufferY + fullRectHeight - radius, radius, 0.0f, M_PI_2, 0);

CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, pointZero.x, pointZero.y);

CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextAddPath(context, path);

CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0f);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.1f);
CGContextFillPath(context);

CGContextAddPath(context, path);
CGContextStrokePath(context);

}
```

[image]

Comment: Is the image above the output of your code, or is this the Siri screenshot you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I have added my output. it's the second image..

Answer (score 2):

The fill color is mostly likley white with an opacity of about 10%. So the original background (a fabric like pattern) shines through and becomes slightly brighter. The border color is white as well, but with an opacity of about 30%.

In addition, there's slight shadow at the right and at the bottom of the border.

For the colors, you approximately need:

```
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextSetShadow(context, CGSizeMake(-15f, -20f), 1.0f);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0f);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.1f);
CGContextFillPath(context);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);

CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.3f);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

Comment: how do I apply borderColor and fill color in the code. If I set it, only one of borderColor or fill color is set and the other one is ignored.

Comment: @Jacob: And yet another update for the shadow effect. But i don't have much experience with the correct parameters.

Comment: @codo.. no luck :(.. i only get the fill color.. also I changed to CGContextDrawPath(context,  kCGPathStroke);

Comment: @Jacob: My code indeed had a mistake. But it's CGContextStrokePath(context) instead of CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke).

Comment: Quartz isn't an easy API to simply pick up in an afternoon.

Comment: Just saying stick with it.  If I wanted to help, I would have posted an answer and not a comment.

Comment: @codo.. I solved the issue of the stroker.. plz see the updated code. But, my colors are still not quite there. I also tried ur color values, it is displayed white.

Comment: @Jacob: Your result looks quite good already. The main difference at the moment is your overall background, which is far brighter than Apple's. Furthermore, the line width should be slightly increased.